# playframework[1.2.4] 500 html page

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In non IE browser, I can see my custom message on 500.html page. However in IE i get the generic 500 page page that IE throws.

How can I prevent IE from showing generic 500 page and showing my modified 500.html page?

```
      catch (Exception ex)
       {

           error("There was an issue connecting to the database. Contact Support");

       }
```

Would like to do something like above if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE will [display custom error pages only if they're big enough](http://perishablepress.com/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/). For a HTTP 500 error page, it needs to be bigger than 512 bytes. (If that's too much for your page, you can just include some junk inside a comment.)